# Add sub menu items dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```js
$(function(){

     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

     $(".side-nav .collapse").on("hide.bs.collapse", function() 
     {   
      $(this).prev().find(".fa").eq(1).removeClass("fa-angle-right").addClass("fa-angle-down");
     });

      $('.side-nav .collapse').on("show.bs.collapse", function() 
      {                                    
        $(this).prev().find(".fa").eq(1).removeClass("fa-angle-down").addClass("fa-angle-right");        
      });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="investigaciones/favoritas"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-plus"></i>Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-1">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Hosts <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
            </a>
            <ul id="submenu-1" class="collapse">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 1.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a side navigation bar in which menu contains sub menu items . I have to add the submenu items dynamically when clicked on menu items using jquery but it is not working for me .

I want to click on menu using jquery, something like onclick function  and also add the list items dynamically.
i have array=[submenu1, submenu2, submenu3] and want to append this to my menu subitems using jquery.

Comment: Show your jQuery so we can create an example and test.

Comment: see this if it may help, i want to use this jquery

Comment: Please add your code in snippet.

Comment: @Rahul are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap @Revti

Answer (score 1):

Use `append()` to your `<ul>` .
It may look something like :

```
array.forEach(function(item, index){
   let newSubMenu = document.createElement("li");
   let textContent = document.createTextNode(item);
   newSubMenu.appendChild(textContent);
   $('#submenu-1').append(newSubMenu );
});
```

Or you can opt to store the HTML template as a string and append

```
array.forEach(function(item, index){
   let newSubMenu = `<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> ${item}</a></li>`
   $('#submenu-1').append(newSubMenu );
});
```

Comment: and what about the class under li?

Comment: how to add that?

Comment: `newSubMenu.classList.add("className"); `

Comment: <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> i want to add this?

Comment: May be we can go the jQuery way of doing it. Store your HTML string as `let htmlDom = "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i> "+ item + "</a></li>"` and simply do `$('submenu).append(htmlDom)`

Comment: @AravindAnil Can you just put your code in snippet?